# Structure for Passing Data to Page in View/Template

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

I am trying to create an app called deals which would create a block on my home page and display a bunch of deals. This is created in Django/Mezzanine. However, I can't get the dictionary data to properly get recognized by the template. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong:

In my main base.html file I have the following:

```
<div class="col-md-9 middle">
    {% block deals %}
    {% ifinstalled deals %}
    {% include "deals.html" %}
    {% endifinstalled %}
    {% endblock %}
    {% block main %}{% endblock %}
</div>
```

In my home folder I have an app called deals. In that folder there is sub directory called *templates*, which contains the file *deals.html*. This file is being called correctly because the *else* condition shown below is rendering to the page.

This is my deals.html file:

```
<div class="row">
        {% if deals %}
                {% for deals in deals %}
                        <div class="deal col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                        <a href="{{ deal.url }}" target="_blank"><img alt=" {{ deal.title }}" src="{{ deal.image }}" data-holder-rendered="true" style="height: 200px; width: 100%; display: block;"></a>
                                        <div class="caption">
                                                <h3 id="thumbnail-label"><a href="{{ deal.url }}" target="_blank">{{ deal.title }}</a><a class="anchorjs-link" href="#thumbnail-label"><span class="anchorjs-icon"></span></a></h3>
                                                <h4>{{ deal.price }}</h4>
                                                <p>{{ deal.description }}</p>
                                                <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                                                                <a href="{{ deal.url }}" class="btn btn-primary" role="button" target="_blank">View</a>
                                                                <button type="button" class="favoritebutton btn btn-default btn-md" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Click to save">
                                                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart empty"></span>
                                                                </button>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                                                                <img class="providerlogo" src="{{ deal.provider_img }}" alt="{{ deal.provider }}"/>
                                                        </div>
                                                </div>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
                <strong>There are no current deals that match your selection. Try expanding your selection and get going!</strong>
        {% endif %}
</div>
```

Under deals/views.py I have the following:

```
from django.shortcuts import render,render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext

# Create your views here.
def deals(request,slug):
    """Handles the deals"""
    data = {'deals':[{'title':'5 Days 4 Nights in New York City',
                     'price':'$1799',
                     'description':'Check out the city that never sleeps. Go skating in Rockefeller Center or catch a show on Broadway. This is the trip of a lifetime.',
                     'provider_img':'http://static.example.com/20150502/partners/logo/small/xgroupon.png.pagespeed.ic.B-5dk6Jr_C.png',
                     'provider':'Name',
                     'url':'http://www.example.com/deal1',
                     'img':'http://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/03/9b/2d/f2/new-york-city.jpg'},
                     {'title':'Dream trip to the carribbean',
                     'price':'$2199',
                     'description':'Enjoy sun, sand and cocktails. This is a trip of a lifetime to sit back and relax. Forget your busy life and enjoy the carribbean',
                     'provider_img':'http://static.example.com/20150502/partners/logo/small/xgroupon.png.pagespeed.ic.B-5dk6Jr_C.png',
                     'provider':'Name',
                     'url':'http://www.example.com/deal2',
                     'img':'http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02464/caribbean_2464021b.jpg'},
                     {'title':'Airfare and Hotel to Paris',
                     'price':'$2400',
                     'description':'It\'s the city of love. Fabulous food, wine and romance in Paris. This trip includes hotel and airfare. Prices are for two or more people",
                     'provider_img':'http://static.example.com/20150502//partners/logo/small/xgroupon.png.pagespeed.ic.B-5dk6Jr_C.png',
                     'provider':'Name',
                     'url':'http://www.example.com/deal3',
                     'img':'http://cache.graphicslib.viator.com/graphicslib/thumbs674x446/2050/SITours/eiffel-tower-paris-moulin-rouge-show-and-seine-river-cruise-in-paris-150305.jpg'}
                     ]
            }
    return render_to_response('templates/deals.html',data,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Currently the following is being rendered:

```
There are no current deals that match your selection. Try expanding your selection and get going!
```

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong? It seems that the dictionary being sent to the page is not being recognized.

**EDIT**
As suggested the problem seems to be an issue with template tags. I've added the following to the top of 'deals.html':

```
{% deals %}
```

and changed my views.py to:

```
from django.shortcuts import render,render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext

# Create your views here.
@register.inclusion_tag('deals.html')
def deals():
    """Handles the deals"""
    data = {'deals':[{'title':'5 Days 4 Nights in New York City',
                     'price':'$1799',
                     'description':'Check out the city that never sleeps. Go skating in Rockefeller Center or catch a show on Broadway. This is the trip of a lifetime.',
                     'provider_img':'http://static.example.com/20150502/partners/logo/small/xgroupon.png.pagespeed.ic.B-5dk6Jr_C.png',
                     'provider':'Name',
                     'url':'http://www.example.com/deal1',
                     'img':'http://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/03/9b/2d/f2/new-york-city.jpg'},
                     {'title':'Dream trip to the carribbean',
                     'price':'$2199',
                     'description':'Enjoy sun, sand and cocktails. This is a trip of a lifetime to sit back and relax. Forget your busy life and enjoy the carribbean',
                     'provider_img':'http://static.example.com/20150502/partners/logo/small/xgroupon.png.pagespeed.ic.B-5dk6Jr_C.png',
                     'provider':'Name',
                     'url':'http://www.example.com/deal2',
                     'img':'http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02464/caribbean_2464021b.jpg'},
                     {'title':'Airfare and Hotel to Paris',
                     'price':'$2400',
                     'description':'It\'s the city of love. Fabulous food, wine and romance in Paris. This trip includes hotel and airfare. Prices are for two or more people",
                     'provider_img':'http://static.example.com/20150502//partners/logo/small/xgroupon.png.pagespeed.ic.B-5dk6Jr_C.png',
                     'provider':'Name',
                     'url':'http://www.example.com/deal3',
                     'img':'http://cache.graphicslib.viator.com/graphicslib/thumbs674x446/2050/SITours/eiffel-tower-paris-moulin-rouge-show-and-seine-river-cruise-in-paris-150305.jpg'}
                     ]
            }
    return data
```

But now I am getting the following error suggesting that it's not being registered correctly:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/
Django Version: 1.6.11
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Invalid block tag: 'deals'
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to assume that the `deal.deals()` view is automagically called when you include your `deals.html` template somewhere. *That is not how it works* - in Django, "views" are really request handlers, iow code that is called with an HTTP request and returns an HTTP response.

The solution to your problem is a custom template tag - in this case an `inclusion_tag` (as documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags)). Good news: you already have most of the code, so your problem should be solved in a few minutes now.

Comment: I've updated my question to reflect an additional issue.

Comment: You didn't read the whole documentation about template tags, did you ? Your template tags are not supposed to be in yourapp/views.py, cf https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't get it. What goes in view.py and what goes in polls_extra.py? Do you know of any working examples that would explain this?

Comment: Nothing gets in "polls_extra.py". Where did you get the idea you need a "polls_extra.py" file ? As stated, it actually *is* an example. The general case is spelled out in whole letters in the above paragraphs. If you don't understand it, then start with doing the Python official tutorial (so you at least understand what "package" and "module" means).